# Why are my columns wrapping to a new line when their combined width should be 99%?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm currently trying to design a Mendeleiev table using only HTML and CSS (CSS3, including Flexbox).
Basically I need each of the boxes to be 1/18 ~= 5.55% of the window width to be responsive.
However, CSS seems to highly miscalculate this value.

Here is a sample of my code

```css
body {
    size: 15px;
    background: #ff9999;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
.line {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}
.box {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 5.56%;
}
.box:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.weight {
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}
.el {
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.no {
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
.right {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.wrap {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <!-- Debut 4e ligne -->
    <div class="line wrap">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    4.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    He
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Fin 4e ligne -->


    <div class="line">

    </div>


    <div class="line">

    </div>


    <div class="line">

    </div>
</div>
```

It is very repetitive (18 columns), but as you should see when pasting it, there are 4 boxes that will not fit on the line (proven with flex-wrap) even when the total of 18*5.55% = 99.9%.

Why such a difference?

Comment: You've got 5.56% there - 18 times that is more than 100%

Comment: Indeed, but I've also tried with 5.55%, and it is still the same - even so, a little difference like that should only push the last element to the following line, so this isn't the main problem in cause...

Comment: Try to set it to 5.4 and if it doesn't fit, scale it down ever further. At the end you could center all the boxes and/or cover the blank areas with color to hide the margins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply because your boxes have `width` and `padding`. Padding is *additive*, meaning if you do `width: 500px; padding: 10px;`, the result is an element that's 520px wide.

What you can do is apply `box-sizing: border-box;` to your `.box` element to make the padding apply *inward* instead of *outward*, thus maintaining its set width.

```
.box {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 5.56%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

---

**Working snippet:**

```css
body {
    size: 15px;
    background: #ff9999;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
.line {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}
.box {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 5.55%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.weight {
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}
.el {
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.no {
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
.right {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.wrap {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <!-- Debut 4e ligne -->
    <div class="line wrap">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    4.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    He
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="weight">
                    1.00
                </div>
                <div class="el">
                    H
                </div>
                <div class="no">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Fin 4e ligne -->


    <div class="line">

    </div>


    <div class="line">

    </div>


    <div class="line">

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Width, in this context, is in addition to padding and border. Try starting with:

```
.box { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

and you should see a difference. Combined with 5.55% (not 5.56%) width, that fits perfectly for me.